Can't set a cookie from php
I am trying to add a cookie in my add_cookie.php file like so:
<?php

setcookie("TestCookie", 'epic_test', time()+3600);
exit('cookie set');

But when accessing https://my-site.com/add_cookie.php I do see the "cookie set" text, but the cookie is not in fact set. Why is that? This code is straight from the documentation :)
I have also tried adding this code to functions.php file of my theme and the result is the same.

is this a WordPress question? No WordPress code is executed if you go directly to a PHP file this way, this looks like a general PHP question that could be asked on stackoverflow. Be sure to include details of how you are checking/testing the cookie is set, and if your server/host is applying caching
